# How can I float the elements inside a tag to the left or right, like we do in html?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm using the WPF Grid Control, for the layout.. and inside row 2, col 2 I want to put two buttons inside that cell, but without using positioning attributes..

```
<Button Content="Confirm" MinWidth="80" Margin="3" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
<Button Content="Cancel" MinWidth="80" Margin="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" />
```

In this example, both buttons are positioned one over the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place them inside `StackPanel`:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button Content="Confirm" MinWidth="80" Margin="3" />
    <Button Content="Cancel" MinWidth="80" Margin="3" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: For the desired float-like effect, you will want to add Orientation="Horizontal" to the StackPanel.  Also, the HorizontalAlignment values on the Buttons are unnecessary.

Comment: The question says `buttons are positioned one over the other` - so I understood vertical positioning, and in this orientation you can use `HorizontalAlignment` on children.

Comment: Adding the attribute Orientation="Horizontal" to the StackPanel makes the objects floating horizontally.

Comment: I believe "one over the other" refers to the overlapping behavior that the OP wants to eliminate.  HorizontalAlignment="Right" was the OP's attempt to mimic HTML/CSS's float:right.